# Amazon Athena - is there a limit between two request toward Amazon athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I there limit of time between two requests to be executed in Amazon Athena?
For example,  I launch some requests from python code as:

```
the request request1    at time t1
the request request2    at time t2
the request request3    at time t3
```

My question, is there a limitation intervalle between

```
 t1 and t2
t2 and t3
```

Because after 27 requests, I get canceled or failed request.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you please edit your question and explain what you are trying to do, how you tried it (show some code!), what output you got and what you were expecting. Please provide enough information that we can try to reproduce the situation to help you debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you will find the information about the limits of Athena service.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/service-limits.html

Please note the following points in this document:

1. "By default, concurrency limits on your account allow you to submit twenty concurrent DDL queries (used for creating tables and adding partitions) and twenty concurrent SELECT queries at a time. This is a soft limit and you can request a limit increase for concurrent queries.
2. "After you submit your queries to Athena, it processes the queries by assigning resources based on the overall service load and the amount of incoming requests."
3. "The query timeout is 30 minutes."

There isn't mention of time interval limit between queries.